# PHP script to delete zero byte files

Tags: php, file, byte, delete-file, zero

I'm having a problem with zero byte files. Sometimes, randomly it seems, the server I'm working with adds zero byte files into a directory. These files break another script. I can delete the files manually with no problem, but becuase of the extremely tight controls on the server, I can't do things like run batch scripts or cron jobs.

What I think I need is a small script on the front page (the only page, actually) that will run a script every time someone visits. It won't get huge traffic. The script would target a specific directory and delete zero byte files.

I've been experimenting with just something as basic as finding and displaying file sizes, and I'm not having much luck. I've even searched online for solutions to similar problems and I haven't found anything.

I don't expect you to do my coding for me (although I wouldn't turn it down! ; )   ), but if someone could help me with a simple way of even just displaying ONLY the zero byte file names, I might be able to proceed on my own from there. I just can't find a way that makes sense to me. And sorry to say, I have essentially no control over the server.

Comment: i think the better solution would be to get to the root of the problem and prevent these files from being written.

Comment: I wish I had that option, but unfortunately I don't, and the server people won't/can't. I work in a very, very locked down place, and our little web page, can't really call it a site, is just one small thing on this particular server (and it's the only server we can use).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DirectoryIterator` class to loop through the files in the specified directory and `unlink()` them.

Comment: Hi Mike and koopajah (sorry about the earlier typo with your name koopajah), I' very very close. I built a simple script using the DirectoryIterator class, and I can delete files if I have that script inside the target directory. What I need to do is have the script one level up, but I'm not sure how to do that. The original script used "$iterator = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));" and I'm now trying "$captionsDirectory = dirname(__FILE__)."/captions";
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($captionsDirectory);" as seen elsewhere, but it's not working for me. Any ideas?